# How Do I Interpret the Following Lines of Code

Tags: c, pointers, network-programming

```
typedef struct {
int a;
short s[2];
} MSG;
MSG *mp, m = {4, 1, 0};
char *fp, *tp;
mp = (MSG *) malloc(sizeof(MSG));
for (fp = (char *)m.s, tp = (char *)mp->s; tp < (char *)(mp+1);)
*tp++ = *fp++;
```

so i've sussed out from my memory of c programming that the first block is a structure declaration using typedef to define an alias. The alias is MSG?
Next pointer *mp, and struct m = {4, 1, 0} are declared as type MSG.
Next two char pointers are created, *fp and *tp. mp is set equal to malloc(sizeof(MSG)) which is cast to type (MSG *) or type pointer to MSG?.
Next a for loop is set where for fp = the m.s (the s within struct m so to speak) is cast to a pointer to a char, tp = pointer mp set to struct s; and tp < (char *)(mp + 1) or pointer plus 1);)

I'm just really unsure as my memory of c is quite foggy at this point. Could someone correct me or better articulate exactly what this code is doing? I'm trying to discern whether or not I'm ready to start studying a certain book and this is the first block of code.
Next whatever pointer fp points to is incremented set to *tp which is also incremented.

Comment: Yes; `MSG` is the alias.  Yes, `mp` is an uninitialized pointer and `m` is an initialized `MSG` structure.  Yes, `fp` and `tp` are `char *` variables.  The cast isn't necessary in C, but is in C++.   And the code then writes out `memcpy()` — more or less.  It could be written `memmove(mp->s, m.s, sizeof(m.s));` (or `memcpy()` — I don't use that, though).  The `(char *)(mp + 1)` limit on the loop is the start of the structure after the allocated structure.  It could also be written `mp->s[0] = m.s[0]; mp->s[1] = m.s[1];` which might even be faster still.

Comment: In fact, it could simply be written as `*mp = m;` which does initialize `mp->a` but that shouldn't be left uninitialized for long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sup>*Converting comments into an answer.*</sup>

- Yes; `MSG` is the alias.
- Yes, `mp` is an uninitialized pointer and `m` is an initialized `MSG` structure.
- Yes, `fp` and `tp` are `char *` variables.
- The cast isn't necessary in C, but is in C++.
- The code then writes out memcpy() — more or less.

It could be written:

```
memmove(mp->s, m.s, sizeof(m.s));
```

(or you could use `memcpy()` — I don't use that, though). The `(char *)(mp + 1)` limit on the loop is the start of the structure after the allocated structure.

The code could also be written as:

```
mp->s[0] = m.s[0];
mp->s[1] = m.s[1];
```

which might even be faster still.
In fact, it could simply be written as:

```
*mp = m;
```

which does initialize `mp->a` but that shouldn't be left uninitialized for long anyway.  If the `m` structure isn't used again, then the code could eliminate the variable and write:

```
*mp = (MSG){ .a = 4, .s = { 1, 0 } };
```

using a [compound literal](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.2.5) and [designated initializers](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.9), both of which require support for C99 or later.

There are a lot of ways to improve that code snippet.  It leaves one wondering whether that is a good book to be learning from.  It might be worth keeping a sceptical eye open for infelicities in the book.  If it was written in the mid-oughts (200x) or in the last millennium, then there are better excuses for what was written, but is a book that old worth reading?  (There are some books of that era that are still worth reading — see comments below.)

Comment: i'm trying to learn network programming with c however I cant find any resources that go in depth enough? have any suggestions?

Comment: W. Richard Stevens, Bill Fenner, Andrew M. Rudoff [UNIX® Network Programming, Vol 1: The Sockets Networking API, 3rd Edn](https://smile.amazon.com/dp/0131411551) 2003. Also: [UNIX® Network Programming, Vol 1: The Sockets Networking API](http://unpbook.com/) • W Richard Stevens [Unix Network Programming, Vol 2: Interprocess Communications, 2nd Edn](https://smile.amazon.com/dp/0132974290) 1998.  •  Michael Kerrisk [The Linux Programming Interface: A Linux and Unix System Programming Handbook, 1st Edn](https://smile.amazon.com/dp/1593272200) 2010. (Yes, I have a list from which I pick them.)